# 32 bit application does not start (0xC000007b) after vc_redist 64 bit has been installed

Tags: c++, visual-c++

We are testing application deployment on a fresh Win 7 64 virtual machine.

Up to now we installed vc_redist_x86 and our 32 bit application ran without problems.

Now as we are shifting towards 64 bit builds, our prerequisites installer installs vc_redist_x86 and vc_redist_x64 of visual studio 2012.

This setup allows us to run our 64 bit test application however this breaks our 32 bit build.

The executable generates the 0xC000007B messages.

Now the weird part: dependency walker shows that msvcr110.dll are 64 bit. [image: dependency walker]
[(full resolution)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2cDVZ.png)

Both redists are shown in programs.
I've then tried to uninstall the 64 bit redist which completed correctly but dependency walker showed the same issue as it had no effect.

I've only get it to work when reverting the VM and install the x86 redist only

Comment: Hard to explain.  But then DependencyWalker hasn't been maintained in a long time and is not up to the job anymore.  A 32-bit program should be using DLLs from c:\windows\syswow64, not c:\windows\system32

Comment: I wouldn't say that as msdn docs for 2012 still reference dependency walker and it has 64 bit support (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms235265%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) but your point is valid though as I need to drill down how an application resolves it's dependencies

Comment: Well, a deeper analysis with procmon has shown me that on my dev and on the test machine both apps fetch the msvcr and msvcp dlls from the SysWOW64 hive. Uninstalling 64 redist removed msvcr110.dll from system32 and I still see one in SysWOW64

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer is still unclear but has something to do with InstallShield's installer.

As we are installing the dependencies via a separate prerequisites installer it seems to  produce an unstable setup when both vcredists AND merge modules of msvcr are selected.

Removing merge modules and relying fully on vcredist seems to work now.

(Note: The prq for vcredist x86 2012 in InstallShield 2012 Spring LE seems to be buggy too, as it is never installed by the installer, probably due to issues with the prq operating system conditions. A solution on SO proposed using the conditions from the 2010 redist prq, which worked out for us. As the LE edition provided as a poorly replacement of microsofts installer does not provide a prq editor editing the prq xml files by hand is possible but mostly guesswork)